# Is there a program to automate localizations for xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I have been using Google's Translation web site to translate my localizable.strings file to multiple languages, but it is very tedious.

Does anyone know if there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Don't do that! Most people will prefer a non-localized English version to a poorly translated one.

Either contact a localization service (they will translate the .strings files directly) or don't localize your app.

Comment: In the affirmative alongside the contribution of you I think correspondingly.

Comment: Agree on this! The cost seems to be reasonable, as there are services that charge about 5 cent a word, so a translation should not be that expensive...

Comment: 100% agree. We automated it using a Perl script talking to Google Translate service (not free) and the results were mostly wrong. Worse  than non-localised English version. There were so many semantic mistakes in many locales that we finally decided to use external service.